# Permission Denied- iPhone Froze-iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have download my app onto the iPhone, now it says permission is denied and my iPhone also froze!

Is there any way to get my iPhone back to work? and why permission denied message appeared, any ideas? Even I could not able to turn off my iPhone?

Comment: Do you mean downloaded from the app store or run through XCode?  Usually when building through XCode and it says Permission Denied, its because you have not unlocked your device and it has a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find instructions for troubleshooting a frozen iPhone on Apple's web site: [Frozen or unresponsive iPhone](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/assistant/phone/)

Basically, hold down both the home and power buttons for at least ten seconds.

You need to provide more details about your “Permission Denied” error if you want help solving it.